# Highcharts How to create a Grouped, stacked bar chart from csv file using javascript and the Highcharts API

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I am a javascript newb and can't quite wrap my head around how to create a grouped, stacked bar chart from a csv file using Highcharts API and javascript. I've asked this same question at the support forum at highcharts but haven't gotten any takers yet. I've always had great luck here in finding answers. I've created the chart that i want here:

http://maine.gov/mdot/about/assets/hwy/charttest-hbar2.html.

Here is the code for this chart with the series being created from within the highcharts api:

```
var chart;
     $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
           },
           title: {
              text: 'Customer Service Levels'
           },
           xAxis: {
              title:{
                 text: 'Highway Corridor Priority'                     
              },
              categories: ['1', '2', '3'],                  
              labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return  '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:#ed1c24;">'+this.value+'</span>  Safety<br/><br/>  Condition<br/><br/>  Service';
                     },

                  }
           },
           yAxis: {
              min: 0,                  
              title: {
                 text: 'Percent of Miles'
              }
           },
           legend: {
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              reversed: true
           },
           tooltip: {
              formatter: function() {
                 return ''+
                      this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' mi';
              }
           },
           plotOptions: {
              series: {
                 stacking: 'percent'
              }
           },
                series: [
              // for priority 1 corridor
              {
                 name: 'D',
                 data: [304.69, 277.92, 139.94], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#ff647f',
                 stack: 1
              }, {
                 name: 'C',
                 data: [482.5, 499.04, 104.54], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#0095c5',
                 stack: 1
              }, {
                 name: 'B',
                 data: [720.13, 678.64, 299.5], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#ffd600',
                 stack: 1
              }, {  
                 name: 'A',
                 data: [379.02, 415.35, 1475.39],  // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#3cb878',
                 stack: 1
              }, 
              // for priority 2 corridor
               {
                 name: 'D',
                 data: [157.56,99.88,16.34], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#ff647f',
                 stack: 2,
                 showInLegend: false
              }, {
                 name: 'C',
                 data: [374.97,347.18,36.39], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#0095c5',
                 stack: 2,
                 showInLegend: false
              }, {
                 name: 'B',
                 data: [167.21,358.19,210.67], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#ffd600',
                 stack: 2,
                 showInLegend: false
              }, {
                 name: 'A',
                 color: '#3cb878',
                 data: [187.75, 89.15, 680.06], // safety, condition, service
                 stack: 2,
                 showInLegend: false
              },

              // for priority 3 corridor
               {
                 name: 'D',
                 data: [188.79,186.91,36.78], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#ff647f',
                 showInLegend: false,
                 stack: 3
                 }, {
                 name: 'C',
                 data: [507.07,337,209.16], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#0095c5',
                 showInLegend: false,
                 stack: 3
              }, {
                 name: 'B',
                 data: [684.08,582.52,545.03], // safety, condition, service
                 color: '#ffd600',
                 stack: 3,
                 showInLegend: false
              }, {
                 name: 'A',
                 color: '#3cb878',
                 data: [60.54, 299.94, 683.42], // safety, condition, service
                 stack: 3,
                 showInLegend: false

                  }]
        });         

     });
```

Following is the csv:

```
CORRIDOR_PRIORITY|CSL_TYPE|SCORE|CSL_LENGTH
1|Safety|A|391
1|Safety|B|679
1|Safety|C|365
1|Safety|D|202
1|Safety|F|97
1|Service|A|1028
1|Service|B|513
1|Service|C|166
1|Service|D|17
1|Service|F|9
1|Condition|A|357
1|Condition|B|536
1|Condition|C|490
1|Condition|D|133
1|Condition|F|105
2|Safety|A|279
2|Safety|B|286
2|Safety|C|173
2|Safety|D|94
2|Safety|F|128
2|Service|A|799
2|Service|B|101
2|Service|C|33
2|Service|D|4
2|Service|F|22
2|Condition|A|189
2|Condition|B|307
2|Condition|C|241
2|Condition|D|130
2|Condition|F|88
3|Safety|A|488
3|Safety|B|517
3|Safety|C|424
3|Safety|D|226
3|Safety|F|321
3|Service|A|1535
3|Service|B|208
3|Service|C|57
3|Service|D|166
3|Service|F|10
3|Condition|A|380
3|Condition|B|654
3|Condition|C|458
3|Condition|D|275
3|Condition|F|197
4|Safety|A|333
4|Safety|B|507
4|Safety|C|433
4|Safety|D|347
4|Safety|F|344
4|Service|A|1114
4|Service|B|83
4|Service|C|762
4|Service|D|3
4|Service|F|3
4|Condition|A|896
4|Condition|B|525
4|Condition|C|308
4|Condition|D|153
4|Condition|F|71
5|Safety|A|338
5|Safety|B|584
5|Safety|C|697
5|Safety|D|367
5|Safety|F|431
5|Service|A|898
5|Service|B|78
5|Service|C|1434
5|Service|D|5
5|Service|F|3
5|Condition|A|747
5|Condition|B|787
5|Condition|C|509
5|Condition|D|253
5|Condition|F|103
```

The first number would be the stack number. The last number is the mileage. We may be able to format the csv differently also if that makes a difference - it's coming from BIQuery. Perhaps stack#|grade|safety#|condition#|service#.

Due to the multidimensional data, I'm completely confused as to how to pass the data to the chart API.

Comment: Have you got a csv that you want to work with? Knowing the format of that would be useful. Here is your example neatened up a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc5tj/1374/

Comment: Hello - thanks for your reply. I'ved added the csv to my post.